# Процесс обработки клиентского запроса в контейнере сервлетов

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Запрос прилетает на сервер.

> Вопрос №1.
>
> Как сервер оценивает что он не может просто вернуть html страницу, а
>   нужно отдать в контейнер? Как контейнер понимает что этот запрос для
>   вот этого приложения, не дергает же он все web.xml файлы / не
>   считывает все аннотации @WebServlet ?

Запрос попадает в контейнер, тот уже знает к какому приложению нужно стучаться. Многие источники пишут следующее:

*Контейнер сервлетов создает объекты `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse` и передает их в метод `service`.*

Но как известно, если есть какие-либо фильтры для данного `url`, то сперва отработают они, а только затем метод service сервлета.

Метод фильтра doFilter принимает 3 параметра: ServletRequest, ServletResponse и FilterChain. Последний оставим за скобкой.

> Вопрос №2.

Контейнер создает `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse` и для фильтра присваивает эти экземпляры типам родительского интерфейса `ServletRequest` и `ServletResponse`? Или же создает экземпляры `ServletRequest` и `ServletResponse`, а уже перед вызовом service формирует экземпляры `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse`? Или может вообще ни то ни другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ №1**

Дёргает и считывает. Но делает это не на каждый запрос, а только в момент деплоя либо изменения конфигурации приложения. Всё остальное время маппинг URL на сервлеты не меняется, поэтому достаточно сравнивать запрошенный URL с известными парами `(паттерн URL: сервлет)`, чтобы понять, куда передавать запрос.

Аналогично с фильтрами. Для каждого фильтра уже на старте приложения известно к каким URL/сервлетам он будет применяться. На основании этого для каждого запроса строится своя цепочка фильтров, которая оканчивается вызовом метода `service` из сервлета.

Отдача статичных файлов обрабатывается аналогично - это частный случай передачи запроса в сервлет. В некоторых контейнерах это делается встроенными средствами (default сервлет в Tomcat, например), в некоторых приходится создавать специальный сервлет для отдачи статического контента.

**Ответ №2**

`HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse` являются наследниками `ServletRequest` и `ServletResponse` соответственно. А значит, в `HttpServletRequest` есть все методы из `ServletRequest`, и везде, где ожидается `ServletRequest`, можно использовать `HttpServletRequest` (принцип подстановки Лисков).

Сервлет, в общем случае, не ограничивается обработкой запросов, посланных по протоколу HTTP, он может обрабатывать любые известные контейнеру протоколы, посторенные поверх TCP/IP (например, WebSocket). Интерфейсы `ServletRequest` и `ServletResponse` содержат лишь методы, позволяющие работать с потоком данных, в то время как `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse` дополнительно содержат методы, специфичные для протокола HTTP (например, `getHeaders()`). То, какой именно наследник `ServletRequest` и `ServletResponse` создаётся для обработки запроса, определяется настройками контейнера. Например, если он слушает порт 80, и ожидает там запросы по HTTP, то сервлеты приложений, работающих на этом порту, будут получать `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse`.

У интерфейса `Filter` нет специализированных наследников для обработки HTTP запросов, однако, благодаря тому что `HttpServletRequest` наследуется от `ServletRequest`, в фильтр можно передавать `HttpServletRequest`, что и делает контейнер. Дальше разработчик, если он уверен, что фильтр будет обрабатывать только HTTP запросы, может привести параметр к `HttpServletRequest` и дальше работать с этим типом.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за столь развернутый ответ!